# Using Audacity to record a call

Tags: audio, audacity

I set Windows WASAPI, Microphone Array (laptop built in soundcard), 2 (Stereo) like this:

[image]

and it records what I am saying but not the other party. I guess I could run another project to record the speaker... would it be possible to record it in one file?

Edit: this is going to be either a Skype or a Google Hangouts call, not sure which yet and yes I considered legal consequences, both parties are in one party consent jurisdictions.

Edit2: there's a loopback available which allows me to record the speaker but that's all -- there's no device that records both.

Comment: How is the call audio getting to your computer? Is this a softphone or does your phone have an analog-out port? Also, are you in a one- or two-party consent state and have you taken into consideration the legal standards surrounding what you are attempting to do? Please use the EDIT button to add at least the minimum necessary information required to answer your question.

Comment: Edited with details.

Comment: So, you're trying to record audio from an application on your computer, and you're getting your own voice but not the audio from the application. What other audio channels are available to select in Audacity and have you tried those?

Comment: Edited that too.